# Preparing app to verification - google api

Tags: gmail-api

I can't submit my app to google for verification.I'm on the Oauth page when I click on "prepare your app", I get the result: " URL not found
We couldn't find what you were looking for. Try one of the links below."

Has anyone ever had this problem before? How do you prepare the app and then submit it?

Comment: Hello Axel, which kind of app are you trying to submit?

Comment: It's a browser app to read mail.

Comment: Can you share some more information about the error? When exactly does it happen? Thanks!

Comment: @Axel856, same problem. were you able to manage to submit your app now?

Comment: Hello @Hitori, can you share more info about the error please?

Comment: @Hitori we just wait few days...